# How to convert epoch timestamp to current timestamp?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How will I convert epoch timestamp millisecond to current time stamp milliseconds.

My Try:

```
 var time = (resp.timestamp * 1000) + 1980000000;
```

`resp.timestamp` -> epoch timestamp

I have tried adding 5hrs 30 minutes(converted to miliseconds) to the epoch timestamp but I am unable to get current time.

Comment: see this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631928/convert-utc-epoch-to-local-date-with-javascript

Comment: I want it to convert to GMT+5:30

Comment: is 1980000000 the epoch timestamp.

Comment: No, i converted 5 hours and 30 minutes to miliseconds and added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED** try this:

```
 function ToLocalDate () {

        var n = Date.now()
        var d = new Date(n);
        console.log(d);
        console.log(d.getDate());
        console.log(d.getMonth());
        console.log(d.getFullYear());
        console.log(d.getHours());
        console.log(d.getMinutes());
        console.log(d.getSeconds());
       }
    ToLocalDate ();
```

Comment: This results in  1234567890000. What is this value?

Comment: I need to convert into IST. i.e. I need current IST's timestamp.

Comment: see in console it is IST only. and object is : Date {Tue Sep 28 2032 21:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)}

Comment: @NagendraSingh see i have pasted every detail related to date now you can check and let me know if you want any thing else.

Comment: I dont know what does the 1980000000 does, but its not giving the correct value.

`console.log(d.getDate());` gives 28, where as today is 03.
`console.log(d.getMonth())` gives 8, where as today is dec, so 12.

Comment: hey 1980000000 is the value you asked in question to convert.will you please elaborate what you want.

Comment: I need my current time on miliseconds. But when I try to convert that miliseconds in date object it gives GMT date, not the IST one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254801/flot-charts-x-axis-time-issues-aarghhh?rq=1