# Can I have flot xaxis's value sorted from smaller to bigger

Tags: sorting, flot

I am now getting a problem when using flot to display chart in time series.
i have the data as below:
[[gd(2012, 12, 10, 00, 06, 11), 382.94], [gd(2012, 12, 10, 00, 14, 59), 383.86],...[[gd(2012, 12, 12, 00, 06, 11), 382.94],...[[gd(2012, 12, 14, 00, 06, 11), 382.94],...[[gd(2012, 12, 10, 16, 06, 11), 382.94]]
but every time I load this data, the xaxis value will be shown from 18:00 to 4:00. not from 00:00 to 23:00.
below is the result screenshot:
[image]

Do you see that? there are two lines there because the xaxis's is from 18:00 to 04:00, not from 00:00 to 23:00. 
any one can help me on this? 
I have studyed it for a while, but result in failure.
thx.

here is some useful code:

```
    function gd(year, month, day, hour, min, second) { 
         return new Date(year, month - 1, day,hour,min,second).getTime(); 
        }
```

below article did't save my time:
[jquery flot xaxis time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507235/jquery-flot-xaxis-time)

Comment: Flot will not sort your data for you -- you need to to that before you pass it to flot. I would suggest sorting it after you get the timestamp.

Comment: @prmech, The data I passed to it is sorting ok. but I don't know why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have solved this。
In backend, we should convert the time format as total seconds from 1970.1.1

so in C# handler:
we should get total seconds:

```
 DateTime.Parse(dr["GetTime"].ToString()).Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds
```

then In front end, we should use as below:

```
var data= eval(arrStr);
```

then all are ok.
[image]